# jQuery append end of url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url variable `http://blah.com/blah/blah/blah` and I have another url `http://shop.blah.com/` I want to take the first url (blah.com) and add the ending `blah/blah/blah` to the second url `http://shop.blah.com`

So I end up with `http://shop.blah.com/blah/blah/blah`

Any idea of how I could do this?

Comment: is the input domain portion constant, or might it contain other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url1 = 'http://blah.com/blah/blah/blah';
var url2 = 'http://shop.blah.com/';

var newUrl = url2 + url1.replace(/^.+?\..+?\//, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) plugin might come in handy here:

```
var url = $.url(); //retrieves current url
```

You can also get specific parts of the URL like this:

```
var file = $.url.attr("file");
var path = $.url.attr("path");
var host = $.url.attr("host");
...
```

If you need to get Querystring parameters:

```
var parm = $.url.param("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is just to add `shop` to the front of the domain name:

```
var url2 = url1.replace('://', '://shop.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
//this uses the browser to create an anchor
      var blah = document.createElement("a");
//initialize the anchor (all parts of the href are now initialized)
      blah.href = "http://blah.com/blah/blah/blah?moreBlah=helloWorld#hashMark";
      var shop = document.createElement("a");
//initialize the anchor (all parts of the href are now initialized)
      shop.href = "http://shop.blah.com/";
      shop.pathname = blah.pathname; //the blahs
      shop.search = blah.search; //the blah query 
      shop.hash = blah.hash;  // the blah hashMark
      alert("These are the droids you're looking for: "+shop.href); 
    });

    </script>
```